# Put single pid CPU into a variable on Linux

Tags: linux, cpu, pid

I need to put the CPU value of a particular pid into a variable to detect its value.

I am able to get the `pid` of the program by using `pidof` and I am able to get the CPU value by using:

```
ps -p <pid> -o %cpu
```

which gives me:

```
%CPU
14.8
```

But I do no want the `%CPU` part, just the value, to then put into a variable to then question whether it is above 90% or not.

Could you please offer any assistance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename the header using `ps`' `-o field=name` syntax with an empty `name`:

```
cpu_percent=$(ps -p "$yourpid" -o %cpu=)
```

To test whether it's greater than some value, we can strip the decimals (bash can't handle them) and compare:

```
yourpid=$$  # Example using current shell's pid

cpu_percent=$(ps -p "$yourpid" -o %cpu=)
echo "Fractional percent is $cpu_percent"

cpu_percent=${cpu_percent%%.*}
echo "Integer percent is $cpu_percent"

if [ "$cpu_percent" -ge 40 ]
then
  echo "It's more than 40"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you. I have this code but it reports the same regardless of the value of cpu_percent

#!/bin/bash

cpu_percent=$(ps -p 3850 -o %cpu=)

echo $cpu_percent

if [ cpu_percent>40 ]; then
        echo "Do something"
else
        echo "Don't do something"
fi

Comment: @omega1 There are many basic problems with that check (shellcheck points out several). I've added an example for how to do it.

Comment: Great, thanks! This works, although I have discovered that (ps -p "$yourpid" -o %cpu=) does not seem to reflect the CPU usage I see in TOP for example, is there a reason for that? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @omega1 %CPU in `top` shows CPU usage in the last second. CPU% in `ps` shows CPU usage over the lifetime of the process.

Comment: Oh no! I needed it in real time... Without wanting to make you curse me, is there any way to get the same value from `top` rather than from `ps`? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use tail to print the last line

```
ps -p <pid> -o %cpu | tail -n 1
```

If you want it in a variable, do this:

```
percent=$(ps -p <pid> -o %cpu | tail -n 1)
```

The `$()` syntax means "put the result of running the command inside the parentheses into a variable".

Then you can compare like this:

```
# Convert to integer
percent=${percent/.*/}
if [ $percent -gt 20 ]; then
   echo Greater
else
   echo Less
fi
```

Comment: Hi, thanks Mark, but that line gives me a blank line:

ps -p <pid> -o %cpu | awk '{print $2}' give me a blank line

ps -p <pid> -o %cpu | awk '{print $1}' give me the original value with the %CPU above it

Any idea why?

Comment: Hi Mark, I think you got confused by the misformatting of the original question version. The ps output in fact consists of two lines.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: Indeeed! Thank you - I run OSX and the format is different and the OP's formatting was misleading!

Comment: Now that I have booted an Ubuntu virtual machine I see that the other solution is more elegant, and have upvoted it accordingly !

Comment: Thanks Mark, nearly there, and to get it into an integer, as it can report a decimal?

Comment: Updated to truncate decimal part.

Answer (score 0):

To get ps not to print the header material (%CPU, in your case):

```
ps h -p <pid> -o %cpu
```

h option turns off headers

`man ps` for more info

This way, you don't have to use `tail -n 1` as above.